# How to improve homebridge responsiveness

Tags: home-automation

I have 2 issues that I suspect are unrelated, but are somewhat similar:

1. The first time I ask Siri to turn on/off a device after a long period of not using Siri/homebridge, the command fails and Siri tells me the device isn't responding.  The second attempt almost always works and subsequent commands over the following minutes/hours/day all seem to work.
2. Sometimes, when I issue a command to Siri to turn on/off a device, the command immediately succeeds, but after a few seconds, Siri tells me she didn't get a response from the device.

Usually, #1 is followed immediately by #2, but #2 happens randomly/sporadically throughout the day, usually with my cec commands.

My hunch is that #1 has to do with some sort of RPi or homebridge sleep mode.  Does anyone know of settings I can manipulate to always keep the first command of the day to always be ready to go?

My hunch with #2 is that the cec-client is the usual suspect because it takes awhile to run each time.  I'm wondering if I can somehow fork that command and give Siri a pre-emptive success response...  I'm using one of the cec plugins, so maybe it would be better to switch to a command-line call via homebridge-commander so I can echo a response back to Siri before running the cec client.  Has anyone tried to solve this issue before?

Comment: I have strong evidence that the sluggishness may be due to pilight-daemon frequently taking up a ton of CPU. I will post an answer if I confirm after I try disabling the receiver chip.

Comment: Ugh. I turned off the receiver pin and immediately after, it took 2 tries to turn on a vesync outlet and 3 tries to send an RF outlet. I looked in the homebridge log and it is filled with searches every 5 seconds for a wemo outlet that is not plugged in (though I’ve had issues when all are plugged in).